# Sed command can't find value with underscore

Tags: linux, bash, sed, yaml

I'm trying to change values in yaml file using `sed` command (can't use `yq`).
I have a file test.yaml with following:

```
  app1:
    value1: 0
    value2: 7
    value_3: 5
  app2:
    value1: 1
    value2: 6
    value_3: 0
```

With the following command I can change value2 of app2 to 0:

```
sed -i '/app2/ {n;N;s/value2: 6/value2: 0/}' test.yaml
```

But for some reason I can't change value_3 with the same command:

```
sed -i '/app2/ {n;N;s/value_3: 0/value_3: 6/}' test.yaml
```

No error, just nothing changes.

Is there a known bug of sed or some misunderstanding from my side? Please advice.

I tried to use double quotes or backslashes before _ - no luck.

Comment: With `n;N` you're only going two lines deep, but the line you want to change is the third one. That's why using text-processing tools like sed on structured data like YAML will always bite you at some point. Use a YAML processor instead.

Comment: Your first command would change `barvalue2: 635` of `fooapp2973` to `barvalue2: 035` which probably would be undesirable. It's always much easier to match the text you want than to not match similar text you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example I suggest GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/\bapp2:/,/\bvalue2:/{ s/\bvalue2: .*/value2: 0/ }' file.yaml
```

> **\b**: marks a word boundary

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
  app1:
    value1: 0
    value2: 7
    value_3: 5
  app2:
    value1: 1
    value2: 6
    value_3: 3
```

Sure is easy with Ruby:

```
ruby -r yaml -e '
BEGIN{tags=["app2"] }
puts YAML.load($<.read).map{|k,v| 
    [k, v.map{|sk,sv| (sk[/_/] && tags.include?(k)) ? [sk,0] : [sk,sv] }.to_h ] 
}.to_h.to_yaml
' file
```

Prints:

```
---
app1:
  value1: 0
  value2: 7
  value_3: 5
app2:
  value1: 1
  value2: 6
  value_3: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this as robustly and reusably as possible using mandatory POSIX tools, in this case any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v block='app2' -v tag='value_3' -v val='6' '
    NF == 1 {
        inBlock = ( $1 == (block":") ? 1 : 0 )
    }
    inBlock {
        if ( $1 == (tag":") ) {
            sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,"")
            $0 = $0 val
        }
    }
    { print }
' test.yaml
  app1:
    value1: 0
    value2: 7
    value_3: 5
  app2:
    value1: 1
    value2: 6
    value_3: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/\<app2\>/{:a;n;/\<app[0-9]+\>/!{s/(\<value2: ).*/\10/;s/(\<value_3: ).*/\16/;ba}}' input_file
  app1:
    value1: 0
    value2: 7
    value_3: 5
  app2:
    value1: 1
    value2: 0
    value_3: 6
```